# how to create a domain with apache2 lamp

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

I want to create a mail server for which a domain is required. I want to access a particular directory in WWW folder with a domain name instead of writing www/foldername. can I do this??

I tried this:-

```
        # Setup "foldername.tld" Virtual Host
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName foldername.tld
  DocumentRoot /home/user/var/www/foldername

 <Directory /home/user/var/www/foldername>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

I created a file called foldername.tld in /etc/apache2/sites-available/.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 lts.
please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your config file looks correct.
I would have started it by :

```
    <VirtualHost foldername.tld:80>
    (...)
```

This way, you can later create other virtual hosts (if needed).
Using '*:80' will catch all requests going to this server on port 80 to the virtual host only.

Then at DNS level you just have to let `foldername.tld` point to the address of your web server (via an A record or via a CNAME to an already defined A record).

Comment: ok I wrote it as you told me..but I think the index file in the folder should be accesible after writing foldername.tld in address bar am I right?? it's giving me error Server not found!! what to do?

Comment: Does foldername.tld resolve to the IP of your web server ? For instance, if you do `nslookup foldername.tld` at the command line you see the IP address of your web server in the reply ?

Comment: It's giving me an error " connection timed out; no servers could be reached".

Comment: `nslookup` gave you this error ? So you don't have any DNS server configured or you don't have Internet access. How are you doing your tests ? I suppose that the web browser is on a different machine than the server ? How is the network connection between both ?

Comment: ok..I did not configure any dns server. I was making changes in hosts file in my pc. Everything is working on my one laptop.